# Dereference operator (*) differences between char* and int*

Tags: c, pointers, printf, format-specifiers

Why is the operator (`*`) needed to access the value of an `int*` variable but not for `char*`?

```c
char *char_ptr; 
int *int_ptr;
int mem_size = 50;

char_ptr = (char *) malloc(mem_size);
strcpy(char_ptr, "This is memory is located on the heap.");
printf("char_ptr (%p) --> '%s'\n", char_ptr, char_ptr);


int_ptr = (int *) malloc(12);
*int_ptr = 31337; 
printf("int_ptr (%p) --> %d\n", int_ptr, *int_ptr);
```

Output:

```
char_ptr (0x8742008) --> 'This is memory is located on the heap.' 
int_ptr (0x8742040) --> 31337
```

Comment: Just a reminder: Don't forget to provide a `free()` for every `malloc()`.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais, its just a part of the code from a book, Thanks!

Comment: @w33haa But Sean is right: memory leaks are a far bigger problem than calling `printf` with a wrong type of pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the way the `printf` format specifiers work: the `%s` format expects, for its corresponding argument, a *pointer* to a character (more precisely, the address of a `nul`-terminated [*string*](https://www.prismnet.com/~mcmahon/Notes/strings.html) - which can be an array of `char`, an allocated buffer with at least one zero byte in it, or a [*string literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)), so you can just give it the `char_ptr` variable as-is; on the other hand, the `%d` format expects an *integer* (not a pointer-to-integer), so you have to dereference the `int_ptr` variable using the `*` operator.

*Note on Good Programming Style: As mentioned in the comments to your question, be sure to call `free()` at some point on every buffer allocated with `malloc`, or you will introduce [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) into your code. Also see: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073).*

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the expression `*char_ptr`. It has the type `char` and the expression will yield the pointed character that is `'T'` - the first character of the stored string literal.

This is the same as `*int_ptr` that returns the first element of the allocated integer array.

As for the conversion specifier `%s` then it expects an argument of the type char * that points to a string. On the other hand, the conversion specifier `%d` expects an object of the type `int`

You could use the conversion specifier `%c`. to output just a single character of the pointed string like

```
printf( "%c", *char_ptr );
```

Answer (score 0):

For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. From that follows that `*p` is equal to `p[0]`.

In your case `*int_ptr` is equal to `int_ptr[0]`.

If you did the same with `char_ptr` (i.e. `*char_ptr`) you would have `char_ptr[0]` which is a single character, that could be printed with `%d` as well:

```
printf("char_ptr (%p) --> '%d'\n", char_ptr, *char_ptr);
```

This would print the decimal representation of the first character in the string.

Comment: Doesn't answer OP's question and might only confuse him. @Adrian Mole answered the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> "Why is operator (`*`) needed to access the value of an `int*` variable and not for `char*` ?"

Because at the `printf()` function, the format specifier `%s` expects a matching argument of type `char *` - a pointer to a string, while `%d` expects an argument of type `int`.

In the latter case, the dereference operator `*` is required to dereference `int_ptr` and yield the value of the `int` object `int_ptr` points to.

As `char_ptr` is already of type `char*` as required by `%s`, there is no need to dereference it.

---

Side notes:

1.

```
int_ptr = (int *) malloc(12);
```

Note that with `12` Bytes on most modern system you be able to allocate only 1 `int` object as it requires `8` Byte. The remaining `4` Byte are not sufficient to hold another.

If you want to allocate space for only one `int`, use `sizeof(*int_ptr)`:

```
int_ptr = (*int) malloc(sizeof(*int_ptr));
```

2.

Also don´t forget to `free()` the storage allocated by `malloc()` after its use:

```
free(int_ptr);
free(char_ptr);
```

3.

Furthermore there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc()`: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

```
char_ptr = malloc(mem_size);
int_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*int_ptr));
```